# Is it possible to get a single element from XMl with the lowest value?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have successfully created an xml file  with the following format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VDZ>
  <Circuits>
    <Circuit>
      <Phases>1</Phases>
      <Size>4mm</Size>
      <Core>Cu</Core>
      <Ins>PVC</Ins>
      <Len>7</Len>
      <Table>T42</Table>
      <Temp>75</Temp>
      <Earth>NIL</Earth>
      <Points>
        <P ID="0" X="156" Y="132" />
        <P ID="1" X="156" Y="120" />
      </Points>
    </Circuit>
    <Circuit>
      <Phases>1</Phases>
      <Size>4mm</Size>
      <Core>Cu</Core>
      <Ins>PVC</Ins>
      <Len>7</Len>
      <Table>T42</Table>
      <Temp>75</Temp>
      <Earth>NIL</Earth>
      <Points>
        <P ID="0" X="254" Y="72" />
        <P ID="1" X="264" Y="72" />
      </Points>
    </Circuit>
  </Circuits>
</VDZ>
```

I am just wondering if it is possible to select an individual element based on the lowest x value (given that I have potentially hundreds of Circuit elements.

I know how to collect all the points as a list, but not how to get the actual element as a whole. Is anyone able to provide some advice please? I literally have no code because I can't find an example remotely close, so I am starting to think this is not achievable. Kudos to anyone who can point me in the right direction..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xml linq with OrderBy.  The code uses Min to get lowest X value in array of points :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim lowestX As XElement = doc.Descendants("Circuit") _
           .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Descendants("P").Min(Function(y) CType(y.Attribute("X"), Integer))) _
           .FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: jdweng... almost. Unfortunately, the second pair in the XElement can have the lowest X, but I never thought of using an orderby... I was stuck on minimum as part of my LINQ statement. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Although not THE answer, it is the guidance I was looking for. Cheers mate!

Comment: Then use following : .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Descendants("P").Min(Function(y) CType(y.Attribute("X"), Integer)))